# mark_area resetting the Y-axis domain (Altair)

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to use `mark_area()` to display the uncertainty around a time series (shown below). However, when I introduce the new layer, the Y-axis domain of the chart resets to the default.

```
chart = alt.Chart(agg_data).encode(
        x=alt.X(field='date', type='temporal', timeUnit='yearmonth', title='date'),
        y=alt.Y(field=r'concentration', type='quantitative', title=r'[CH4] (ppb)',
            scale=alt.Scale(domain=[1600, 1900])),
        tooltip=[alt.Tooltip(field='date', type='temporal', title='date', format='%Y, %m'),
                 alt.Tooltip(field=r'concentration', type='nominal', title=r'concentration')]
        ).properties(width='container', height=300)

# Add uncertainty bands
bands = chart.mark_area(color='dodgerblue', fillOpacity=0.4).encode(
            x=alt.X(field='date', type='temporal', timeUnit='yearmonth', title='date'),
            y='lower bound:Q',
            y2='upper bound:Q',
        ).properties(width='container', height=300)

l = chart.mark_line(color='dodgerblue')
p = chart.mark_point(color='dodgerblue', filled=True)
layer = alt.layer(bands, l, p)
```

Here is the result I get before adding `bands`:

[image]

and after:

[image]

How can I keep the Y-axis domain from Figure 1, while using `mark_area()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area charts include zero by default. To change this, in the `y` encoding, specify `alt.Scale(zero=False)`:

```python
  y=alt.Y('lower bound:Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
```